# Performance issues on iOS device

Tags: javafx, gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I recently started testing my Gluon Mobile app on my iOS device, but sometimes when I open my app, this popup occurs. Is there any way to fix or avoid this?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default architecture when deploying on iOS with JavaFXPorts is `thumbv7`, as you can see [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/tip/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/ios/IosExtension.groovy?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#IosExtension.groovy-23).

This means the app is created in 32 bits mode.

Since iOS 10.1, Apple is trying to push developers to update their apps to 64 bits [mode](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/ios-10-1-adds-app-may-slow-down-your-iphone-warning-for-32-bit-apps-1524181).

While creating 32-bits apps doesn't mean they have less performance, if you want to avoid the message you need to create the app in 64 bits mode.

For that you can change the `arch` parameter:

command line:

```
./gradlew -Probovm.arch=arm64 launchIOSDevice
```

or on your build.gradle file:

```
jfxmobile {
    ios {
        arch = "arm64"
        ...
    }
}
```